# using tqdm in a for loop inside a funcion

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, tqdm

I am trying to use tqdm to monitor the progress of a for loop that in turn calls a function. The function has another for loop inside it, which also needs to be monitored using tdqm.

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import time

def sleep():
    for i in tqdm(range(10)):
        time.sleep(0.1)
    return None

for j in tqdm(range(2)):
    sleep()
```

I was hoping to see two progress bars, one below the other. The first iterating over two variables and the second iterating over ten. However, it seems that every time the for loop runs, it creates a new progress bar:

[image]

Could anyone suggest a workaround, so that I can see the progress bars the way I described it?

Answer (score 2):

It seems your are using tqdm in a jupyter enviroment. Try with

```py
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
```

If the progress bars do not show, make sure to enable the extension:

`jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension`

[image: notebook example]

Comment: Thank you, @carlduke, this solved the problem!